# Copying and pasting to a worksheet who's name does not equal a value within a list?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste information to certain worksheets. Most of the worksheet names I already know, but there could be one new worksheet added in, which I wouldn't know the name of.

There are 3 worksheets (let's call them WorkSheet1, WorkSheet2, and WorkSheet3) that I don't want to change. I want to copy some values from WorkSheet2 and paste them in all worksheets except 1-3. So far, I have an IF statement with the worksheets I know the names of (WorksheetX,Y, and Z). I am having trouble with the last instance where I wouldn't know the worksheet's name. I have been thinking of using an Or. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim og As Worksheet
Set og = Sheets("WorkSheet2")
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name = "WorkSheetX" Then
    og.Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("WorkSheetX").Range("L4").PasteSpecial
ElseIf ws.Name = "WorkSheetY" Then
    og.Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("WorkSheetY").Range("L4").PasteSpecial
ElseIf ws.Name = "WorkSheetZ" Then
    og.Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("WorkSheetZ").Range("L4").PasteSpecial

'This is where I am having trouble. I won't know the name of the new sheet
'Just that it wont be WorkSheet1,2,3,X,Y, or Z
ElseIf (ws.Name <> "WorkSheet1" Or ws.Name <> "WorkSheet2" 
Or ws.Name  <> "WorkSheet3" Or ws.Name <> "WorkSheetX" Or
ws.Name <> "WorkSheetY" Or ws.Name <> "WorkSheetZ") Then
    og.Range("A1").Copy
    ws.Range("L4").PasteSpecial
End If
Next
```

Comment: Are the 4 worksheet the only ones in the workbook?

Comment: You could use the  index number  or CodeName.

Comment: There could be anywhere from 4 to 12 worksheets. I know the names for all except one, but they might not all be included in the workbook. So I'm not sure if the index would work, because the amount of known sheets is variable

Comment: Loop through all the worksheets in the workbook, Use an IF OR statement to test all worksheets. (Don't include the 4 worksheet names you want). e.g. `For each worksheet in workbook` `If worksheet is not ws1, or ws2, or etc.` Then do your copy.

Comment: How should I write out the paste line? I tried this and the issue is that pastes it on the new sheet, but also pastes it on all worksheets. I do the for each ws in worksheets, then an IF with an OR, then the copy then ws.Range("L4").PasteSpecial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code to accomplish your task.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Change the sheet names you don't want to perform you copy_paste
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet_n")).Visible = False

    For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Visible = True Then
                ws.Range("L4").Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
            End If
    Next ws

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet_n")).Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

## A Few Worksheets

```
Option Explicit

Sub AFewWorksheets()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim og As Worksheet

  Set og = Sheets("WorkSheet2")

  For Each ws In Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name
      Case "Worksheet1", "Worksheet2", "Worksheet3"
      Case Else
        og.Range("A1").Copy
        ws.Range("L4").PasteSpecial
    End Select

  Next

End Sub
```